# WordPress Yoast SEO canonical tag trailing slash on custom post type categories

Tags: seo, wordpress, canonical-url, rel-canonical

In my theme is a custom post type for events.

On the category pages for these custom post types no trailing slash is being added to the URL in the canonical tag when there should be.

What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Look at this:

```
function append_query_string( $url, $post ) {
    if ( 'tour-item' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
        return add_query_arg( $_GET, $url );
    }
    return $url . '/';

    if ( 'destinations' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
        return add_query_arg( $_GET, $url );
    }
    return $url . '/';
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'append_query_string', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: If this is a solution, can you add how the OP would apply it?